# i'm not finding sent password reset link in my mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm facing a problem with `Laravel` `password` `reset`. when i enter my email it says:

> We have e-mailed your password reset link!

**here is a screen**

[image]

**PROBLEM: but i'm unable to see any reset link in my mail**

Here is what I did in my `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail  
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example777@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

If I change driver to `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` then getting this error:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: give correct SMTP credentials

Comment: @Naincy, yeh i'm using correct credentials here... that is for example above

Answer (score 0):

Try to set host value in config/mail.php as your host value,then run these commands

php artisan optimize,
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan route:clear

Thank you